# plpgsql $[position] is relative?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
create or replace function exc_using(int, text) returns int as
    $$
        declare i int;
        begin
        for i in execute 'select * from generate_series(1,$1) ' using $1+1 loop
            raise notice '% ', i;
            raise notice 'i + i *3: % ', i + i * 3;
        end loop;
        execute 'select $2 + $2 * 3 + length($1) '
            into i using $2, $1;
        return i;
        end
    $$
language plpgsql;
```

seems **A**

```
    execute 'select $2 + $2 * 3 + length($1) '
        into i using $2, $1;
    return i;
```

is the same as:
**B**

```
    execute 'select $1 + $1 * 3 + length($2) '
        into i using $1, $2;
    return i;
```

My preception is that $2 Absolutely refer to function second argument that data type is text. but seems plpgsql $[position] is relative. But I cannot get manual reference for this edge case.

Comment: Why use positional parameters at all? Why not give your function arguments proper names and avoid the confusion of two different levels that interpret `$x`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because the code is from `src / test / regress`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course they are relative.  What else would they be?  But what are they relative to?

Inside the EXECUTE string, the $1 and $2 are relative to the USING.  Outside, they are relative to the function parameters.

Comment: I vaguely get it, thanks you jjanes.